# pandas and if else produces unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry this is a simple one but why does the below code produce:

```
   val  trans
0    1      1
1    2      1
2    3      1
3    4      1
4    5      1
5    6      1
6    7      1
```

and not:

```
   val  trans
0    1      0
1    2      0
2    3      0
3    4      1
4    5      1
5    6      0
6    7      0
```

trans should be 1 for all vals greater equal 4 and less than 6?!

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'val':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.info())

df['trans'] = [1 if x >= 4 & x < 6 else 0 for x in df['val']]

print(df)
```

Comment: don't use the bit and operator, instead you can write `if 4 <= x < 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because working with scalars in list comprehension use `and` instead bitwise `AND` working with arrays:

```
df['trans'] = [1 if x >= 4 and x < 6 else 0 for x in df['val']]

print(df)
   val  trans
0    1      0
1    2      0
2    3      0
3    4      1
4    5      1
5    6      0
6    7      0
```

Vectorized solutions:

```
df['trans'] = np.where((df.val >= 4 ) & (df.val < 6) , 1, 0)
df['trans'] = ((df.val >= 4 ) & (df.val < 6)).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['trans'] = np.where(df.val.between(4, 5), 1, 0)
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense, curious does oen use & or and for .query?

Comment: It looks a little odd but could also use `np.where(df.val.between(4, 5), 1, 0)` here to generate the boolean array in one go rather than and'ing the two selections.

Comment: @cs0815 - Good question, I found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=query#query-python-versus-pandas-syntax-comparison) for sample - `Use English instead of symbols:` so in query is possible use `not`, `or` and `and` whcih is transplated to bitwise operations

Comment: thanks. as someone coming from R spoiled by dplyr I find the different ways to achieve things in pandas very confusing ...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using bitwise `&`. Instead, you should use `and` because its a list comprehension. Code:

```
df['trans'] = [1 if x >= 4 and x < 6 else 0 for x in df['val']]
```

Another method (discussed in comments by @Sembei):

```
df['trans'] = [1 if 4 <= x < 6 else 0 for x in df['val']]
```

Output:

```
   val  trans
0    1      0
1    2      0
2    3      0
3    4      1
4    5      1
5    6      0
6    7      0
```